# Fragments aren´t added to backstack when using Navigation UI with Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I´m using the Android Navigation Component to create an App with a Navigation Drawer. However if if change the current Fragment via the Navigation Drawer and then press back the app always returns to the start Fragment of the Navigation Graph.
I could only find solutions how to remove Fragments from the Backstack while using the Navigation Component but not how to add them.

I´ve already added the other Fragments as root fragments in the AppBarConfiguration for the NavController but that doesn´t change the behavior. 
When using the standard `navController.navigate()` in other parts of the app the Fragments are added to the Backstack correctly. Only when I´m switching Fragments from the Navigation Drawer they aren´t added to the Backstack.

I´ve also tried changing the actions between the Fragments (e.g. `popUpTo`and `popUpToInclusive`), but it seems like the Navigation Component isn´t using these, as it doesn´t change anything.

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstaceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DrawerLayout drawer_layout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);

    appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.homeFragment, R.id.Fragment1,
                          R.id.Fragment2, R.id.Fragment3).setDrawerLayout(drawer_layout).build();

    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}
```

**nav_graph.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="package.fragments.homeFragment"
        android:label="@string/home_fragment_label"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/Fragment1"
        android:name="package.fragments.Fragment1"
        android:label="@string/fragment1_label"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment1" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/Fragment2"
        android:name="package.fragments.Fragment2"
        android:label="@string/fragment2_label"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment2" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/Fragment3"
        android:name="package.fragments.Fragment3"
        android:label="@string/fragment3_label"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment3" />
</navigation>
```

When switching from `Fragment1` to `Fragment2` and then pressing back, I would expect the app to go back to `Fragment1`, but instead the app redirects to `homeFragment`.
Is there any way to prevent the Navigation Component from always returning to the start Fragment instead of the previous Fragment?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I´ve managed to generate the desired behavior. I just overlooked the relevant part of the documentation. As stated in the [documentation of the NavigationUI](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI.html#onNavDestinationSelected(android.view.MenuItem,%2520androidx.navigation.NavController)) you need to add `android:menuCategory = "secondary"` to the menu items in the menu of the Navigation View. By adding this line in the XML file the backstack isn´t popped when switching to the corresponding Fragment and therefore the app returns to the previous Fragment when pressing back.